# python string, delete character, count from right

Tags: python

I have some strings I created with elements coming from many sources, number of elements will vary each time the program is run; I created a sample string that my program creates now.
I want to count in [:-3] for the following string and delete the last comma:

```
'{"SEignjExQfumwZRacPNHvq8UcsBjKWPERB":1.00000000,"SCaWymicaunRLAxNSTTRhVxLMAB9PaKBDK":2.80000000,"SGFHTxuRLttUShUjZyFMzs8NgC1JopSUK6":1.20000000,}'
```

So my string looks like:

```
'{"SEignjExQfumwZRacPNHvq8UcsBjKWPERB":1.00000000,"SCaWymicaunRLAxNSTTRhVxLMAB9PaKBDK":2.80000000,"SGFHTxuRLttUShUjZyFMzs8NgC1JopSUK6":1.20000000}'
```

I just cant quite get there, help appreciated.

Comment: s.replace(",", "")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the third last character from the string you can use:

```
string[:-3] + string[-2:]

>>> string = "hellothere"
>>> string[:-3] + string[-2:]
'hellothre'
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use rsplit to split on the right most occurrence of a substring (limiting to two results) and then join them with an empty string

```
''.join(s.rsplit(',', 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = '{"SEignjExQfumwZRacPNHvq8UcsBjKWPERB":1.00000000,"SCaWymicaunRLAxNSTTRhVxLMAB9PaKBDK":2.80000000,"SGFHTxuRLttUShUjZyFMzs8NgC1JopSUK6":1.20000000,}'

a[:len(a) - 2] + a[len(a) - 1:]
```

You could obviously use different expressions in the brackets, I just wanted to show that you could use any expressions you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with `rfind` to find the last comma

```
s = '{"SEignjExQfumwZRacPNHvq8UcsBjKWPERB":1.00000000,"SCaWymicaunRLAxNSTTRhVxLMAB9PaKBDK":2.80000000,"SGFHTxuRLttUShUjZyFMzs8NgC1JopSUK6":1.20000000,}'
idx = s.rfind(",")
s[:idx]+s[idx+1:]
```

you get,

```
'{"SEignjExQfumwZRacPNHvq8UcsBjKWPERB":1.00000000,"SCaWymicaunRLAxNSTTRhVxLMAB9PaKBDK":2.80000000,"SGFHTxuRLttUShUjZyFMzs8NgC1JopSUK6":1.20000000}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regex:

```
>>> print re.sub(r ",(?=[^.]*$)", r '', s)
{"SEignjExQfumwZRacPNHvq8UcsBjKWPERB":1.00000000,"SCaWymicaunRLAxNSTTRhVxLMAB9PaKBDK":2.80000000,"SGFHTxuRLttUShUjZyFMzs8NgC1JopSUK6":1.20000000}
```

This will match a `','` all before a any potential NOT `','`. It matches the last `','` right before the end of a string.